# composite key for nested data structure in java collection

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, composite-key

The datastructure I need is ,

A->B->C

where A can have multiple B values

and B has one to one association with C

A,B are integers;C is a POJO

I  arrived at Map(A,(Map(B,C)))
But this is not very straight forward to traverse.
like to,

Fetch all b associated with A

Fetah all C associated with (A,B)

Also the data is in millions.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: How can A have multiple Bs if A is just an integer?

Comment: when I say Integer I mean like a department-id associated to multiple subject-id.

Comment: This looks like a simple use case for a relational database. Especially for millions of records.

Comment: but I need this to be on java collection..not database..